# AddEventListener to multiple elements and return their values - How?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, callback, closures, addeventlistener

I have a list of categories:

```
<ul id="categories">
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li>bbb</li>
    <li>ccc</li>
</ul>
```

And I want to return the value of the category onClick.
So I tried to pick them all, create an `addEventListener` for each of them. But I don't know how I can get the value of `cat.textContent` to the outside of the scope of the callback or the function itself...

```
async getCategoryNameOnClick() {
    var cats = document.querySelectorAll('#categories li')
    cats.forEach( (cat) => {
        cat.addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log(cat.textContent)
        })
    })
}
```

I tried resolving with a promise, but then, after it is resolved it doesn't work anymore. Neither using `var`

Comment: You cannot return the value for multiple reasons: The event happens at some point in the future, not when the function is called. The event will happen multiple times but a function can only return once. You can solve the first problem with promises but even a promise only resolves once, so it wouldn't pick up future clicks. So how exactly do you want to process the click events? The simplest solution would be to pass a callback  and have the event handler call the callback. Or you can use something like https://rxjs.dev/ as a higher level abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so first, you placed it in a function that is not call, and made it an async function with out needing on, seconded you didn't make list click able with out an anchor or button tag. So here is what I cam up with that will give you what your asking for.

```
    <ul id="categories" >
  <li><button>aaa</button></li>
    <li><button>bbb</button></li>
    <li><button>ccc</button></li>
</ul>

let cats = document.querySelectorAll('#categories li');

cats.forEach( (cat) => {
       cat.addEventListener('click', () => {
             console.log(cat.textContent)
         })
});
```

I put them in buttons but you could of used anchor tags as well.

Comment: *"you didn't make list click able with out an anchor or button tag"* While it's good to use a button or a link, it's not necessary. Click events also trigger on other elements.

Comment: As far as I know `button` or `a` elements aren't needed to add an event listener to an element in the DOM. Your reply doesn't answer how to get the `cat.textContent` outside of the callback. And doesn't solve the problem of clicking it more than once and keeping it returning and working. The function is not called, because it's an excerpt of a whole class. But this is the only needed part for illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the button click logic that catches the selected li text. Hope this answers your question.

```js
var categoresBtn = document.querySelector("button");
var dropdownOptionsContainer = document.querySelector(".options-container");
var categoriesOption = document.querySelectorAll(".option a");

categoresBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  dropdownOptionsContainer.classList.toggle("open")
});

//logic to catch the clicked li tag
var clickFn = function(e) {
  console.log("Selected <li>: ", e.target.innerText);
  e.preventDefault()
  dropdownOptionsContainer.classList.remove("open");
  categoresBtn.innerHTML = this.text;
  var activeLink = document.querySelector(".option .active");

  if (activeLink) {
    activeLink.classList.remove("active");
  }
  this.classList.add("active");
}

for (var i = 0; i < categoriesOption.length; i++) {
  categoriesOption[i].addEventListener("mousedown", clickFn, false);
}
```

```css
.dropdown-container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.dropdown-container button {
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #9b9b9b;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  min-width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-container button:after {
  content: '▾';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0%;
  color: rgb(142, 142, 142);
}

.dropdown-container .dropdown-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-container .dropdown-wrap .options-container {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8) translate3d(-20px, 0px, 0);
  transform: scale(0.8) translate3d(-20px, 0px, 0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.5, 2, 0.5, 0.75), -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.5, 2, 0.5, 0.75);
  transition: opacity 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.5, 2, 0.5, 0.75), -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.5, 2, 0.5, 0.75);
  transition: opacity 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.5, 2, 0.5, 0.75), transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.5, 2, 0.5, 0.75);
  transition: opacity 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.5, 2, 0.5, 0.75), transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.5, 2, 0.5, 0.75), -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.5, 2, 0.5, 0.75);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-container .dropdown-wrap .options-container.open {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: scale(1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 5;
}

.dropdown-container .dropdown-wrap .options-container li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-container .dropdown-wrap .options-container li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  color: #2975DA;
}

.dropdown-container .dropdown-wrap .options-container li a:hover {
  color: #2269c7;
}

.dropdown-container .dropdown-wrap .options-container li a.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #9b9b9b;
  color: #9b9b9b;
}

.dropdown-container .dropdown-wrap .options-container li a.active:hover {
  color: #9b9b9b;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-container">
  <div class="dropdown-wrap">
    <button>Categories</button>
    <ul id="categoriesDDl" class="options-container">
      <li class="option">
        <a href="#">aaa</a>
      </li>
      <li class="option">
        <a href="#">bbb</a>
      </li>
      <li class="option">
        <a href="#">ccc</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Uhmm.. This answer adds unnecesary CSS, and HTML markup. It's a pretty creative answer, though. But Ignoring all that, basically what you did was to use a callback function, and get the `innerText`. So you been able to retrieve the value of the clicked element within the callback (the same as I did), but not to extract it from the callback for further use anywhere else. That is what I was asking for. I think that using `e.preventDefault()` or not doesn't make a difference in this case.